# Create a 2 Dimentional C++ array for every month's sales report and determine the Highest and lowest MONTH of sales

Tags: c++

Problem:
Write a program in C++ using two-dimensional array that creates the sales report from January to December in CJ Marketing Incorporated. Determine the highest and lowest month of sales.

I am new to Programming and here's my code. I am looking for ways to show what month the highest and lowest sales came from. Any tips on how can I improve this code will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define ARRAY_SIZE_ROW 6
#define ARRAY_SIZE_COLUMN 2
#define ARRAY_SIZE 12

int main()
{
string d[ARRAY_SIZE_ROW][ARRAY_SIZE_COLUMN]={{"January", "February"}, {"March", "April"}, {"May", "June"}, {"July", "August"}, {"September", "October"}, {"November", "December"}};
int a[ARRAY_SIZE_ROW][ARRAY_SIZE_COLUMN]={};
int b[ARRAY_SIZE_ROW][ARRAY_SIZE_COLUMN]={};
int c=0, e=0;

for (int i=0; i<ARRAY_SIZE_ROW; i++)
{
   for (int j=0; j<ARRAY_SIZE_COLUMN; j++)
   {
     cout << "Enter the sales for  "<<d[i][j]<<" ";
     cin >> b[i][j];
   }
 }

c = b[0][0];
e = b[ARRAY_SIZE_ROW][ARRAY_SIZE_COLUMN];

for (int i=0; i<ARRAY_SIZE_ROW; i++)
{
    for (int j=0; j<ARRAY_SIZE_COLUMN; j++)
    {
        if (b[i][j] > c)
        {
            c = b[i][j];
        }
        if (b[i][j] < e)
        {
            e = b[i][j];
        }
    }
}

cout << "\nGreatest sales is: " << c;
cout << "\nSmallest sale is: " << e;
cout<<"\n";
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Please post questions looking for code review to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: This question is more suitable for [Codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 0):

You're not using array named 'a', so you can delete it.
Also you can use const variables instead of using define.